# Tooltip set on a button displaying a modal dialog is reappearing after closing the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem description is in the title - the tooltip reappears when I close the modal dialog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divModal" data-tooltip="tooltip" title="Tooltip!">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
</button>
```

see it happening here :
http://jsfiddle.net/2gdrL6sf/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the button is gaining focus when the modal is closed. To get around the tooltip showing again after the modal is closed you could restrict the tooltips trigger to a hover like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
});
```

I forked your JSFiddle and have [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/5kd0vz78/) you can check out.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! It seems to be working. I'm curious, is it possible to not focus the button at all on modal close?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible to not focus the button, but you'd have to track down what is causing the focus. There are modal events for showing and hiding you can hook into that may help with that. You can [check the docs for available events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage).

Comment: All right, thanks :) I believe I am not a veteran enough in javascript to inspect a framework's code..!

Answer (score 1):

In the button click handler, add a blur call to remove focus.

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $(this).blur();
    $('#myDialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Buttons need to have focus and display a tooltip when not clicked so that assistive technologies can be effective. Somebody that's unable to use a mouse might need to tab between buttons.  Setting the tooltip to only trigger on hover removes that capability.